# google sheets calendar detailed result?

Tags: google-sheets, calendar

So imagine the example in the image, this is a calendar and lets take the name Peter for example

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yhnYIV7LrE_wTENia5D2020P6kq5pFeDnFOm0yGU4-k/edit?usp=sharing
```

after having a calendar, imagine that I want to filter 1 name on the whole calendar and get all the times and days that that person is in the calendar

example:

Peter 14 feb 11:00 12:00 13:00 14:00
peter 16 feb 10:30 11:00
etc etc..

is there any way to do this ? instead of extraction that information one by one just like i did to write this message ?

filters but they seem to not be helpfull since i can not get the data in the format I described

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get one possible result with the next formula:

```
=FILTER(TOCOL(MAP(B3:28;LAMBDA(m; TEXT(INDEX(2:2; COLUMN(m));"DD MMM")&" - "&TEXT(INDEX(A:A;ROW(m));"hh:mm")));;1);REGEXMATCH(TOCOL(B3:28;;1);A33))
```

I put the name in A33. You can use TEXTJOIN if you want them in only one cell

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=tocol(index(if(regexmatch(B3:Z28&"";A35);text(B2:Z2;"dd mmm - ")&to_text(A3:A28);));1;1)
```

[image]

Comment: Also are Peter/PEter and ricky/Ricky one and same OR to be considered different altogether?!